# how can i get data out of DIV using html parser in java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

i am using Java html parser([link text](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)) to try to parse this line.

```
<td class=t01 align=right><div id="OBJ123" name=""></div></td>
```

But I am looking for the value like I see on my web browser, which is a number. Can you help me get the value?

Please let me know if you need more details.
Thanks

Comment: That bit of html is not going to display any text in your browser, unless some javascript manipulates it. If you mean some other value, please point us to the value you're interested in.

Comment: ok for example i want to get the values like the browser is showing for this link.How can i get. Yes must be the java script.   http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/fo/foquote.jsp?key=FUTSTKINFOSYSTCH30DEC2010--24DEC2010&symbol=INFOSYSTCH&flag=1

Comment: i hope the link source will help you understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, all you have to do is find all of the `DIV` elements that also have an id of `OBJ123` and take the first result's value.

```
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null); // you can also filter here

NodeList divs = nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(
  new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("DIV"), 
    new HasAttributeFilter("id", "OBJ123")));

if( divs.size() > 0 ) {
  Tag div = divs.elementAt(0);
  String text = div.getText(); // this is the text of the div
}
```

UPDATE: if you're looking at the [ajax url](http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/fo/foquote_tab_ajax.jsp?key=FUTSTKINFOSYSTCH30DEC2010--24DEC2010&symbol=INFOSYSTCH&flag=1), you can use similar code like:

```
// make some sort of constants for all the positions
const int OPEN_PRICE = 0;
const int HIGH_PRICE = 1;
const int LOW_PRICE = 2;
// ....

NodeList nl = parser.parse(null); // you can also filter here

NodeList values = nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(
  new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("TD"), 
    new HasAttributeFilter("class", "t1")));

if( values.size() > 0 ) {
  Tag openPrice = values.elementAt(OPEN_PRICE);
  String openPriceValue = openPrice.getText(); // this is the text of the div
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to scrape this website http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/fo/foquote.jsp?key=FUTSTKINFOSYSTCH30DEC2010--24DEC2010&symbol=INFOSYSTCH&flag=1, the divs will not contain values upon page load and will only be populated when javascript executes. Unless your parser can execute javascript, you will have to scrape it some other way, maybe look at the javascript and scrape that instead.

Comment: any pointers to any tool to find the java script and scrape it or parser which can execute java script? any pointer to any documentation related to it will also be appreciated.

Comment: what you really want to do is scrape this url: http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/fo/foquote_tab_ajax.jsp?key=FUTSTKINFOSYSTCH30DEC2010--24DEC2010&symbol=INFOSYSTCH&flag=1 and find all `TD` tag with `class=t1` and make an index of that so that the 1st one is the open price, 2nd one is high price, etc.. you will have to play around with the positions.